# In terraform modules variable ensure that one of the two variable is always present

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules, terraform-variables

In terraform modules variables, how to ensure that one of the two variables is always present and not both?

modules/app_function

```
variable app1_version {
  description = "APP1 Version"
  type = string
}
variable app2_version {
  description = "APP2 Version"
  type = string
}
```

##Usage
app/myapplications

```
module "myapp1" {
  source        = "../modules/app_function/"
  app2_version = "v4.4"
  other_variable = abc
}
module "myapp2" {
  source        = "../modules/app_function/"
  other_variable = abc
}
```

`myapp1` should be valid and `myapp2` should not be valid.

Comment: @TPS what does that mean? Are you taking about variable declaration or variable value or both?

Comment: app1_version OR app2_version must be present in the code when I am using this module variable file. Also updated the question.

Comment: If you have only 2 choices, why not use `bool` value, `true` for `myapp1`, `false` for `myapp2`?